# How do I calculate the year on year increase of a property price given that I only have the initial price and final price?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to find out how can I calculate the year on year increase of property price if I only have 3 information:

1. the starting price in 2021 is 200k.
2. the current price in 2024 is 280k.
3. the duration is 3 years from 2021 to 2024.
4. Assumption: the increase is constant each year.

Comment: You can't. Without more data it is possible that the price stays constant for  $2$ years and $364$ days and increase of $80k$ in the last day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the yearly increase $q$ is constant, we get that $$200q^3=280,$$ thus $q=\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{5}}\approx 1.1187$, so the price increases by around 12% each year. But as a comment noted, in general, without the assumption of the increase being constant, we can't solve the problem.